# smoothScrollToPosition() working on intermittently in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a comments section in one of my activities. A user can post a comment. The comment goes to the top of the `RecyclerView` (index 0) as desired. I'm invoking the `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` on the `RecyclerView`. This only works intermittently. It works when, the recylerview has already been scrolled before post is commented. Then it scrolls to index 0...the new comment. However if the item `index 0` is showing before the comment is posted the smoothScrollToPosition doesn't work. When I scroll manually the comment is as expected at index 0. Any advice?

**EDIT**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mCommnetsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(commentsQuery) {

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {

                if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                    mRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        };



        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecycler.setAdapter(mCommnetsAdapter);





    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mCommnetsAdapter.startListening();

        mMatchRegistration= mMatchRef.addSnapshotListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mMatchRegistration !=null){

            mMatchRegistration.remove();
            mMatchRegistration=null;

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onRating(Rating rating) {

        addRating(mMatchRef, rating)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Rating added");

                        // Hide keyboard and scroll to top
                        hideKeyboard();
                        mRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

        });


    }
```

I have a base adapter class where notifyItemChange() is implemented.

```
public abstract class FirestoreAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>
        implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
.....

public void stopListening() {
        if (mRegistration != null) {
            mRegistration.remove();
            mRegistration = null;
        }

        mSnapshots.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void setQuery(Query query) {
        // Stop listening
        stopListening();

        // Clear existinkodig data
        mSnapshots.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Listen to new query
        mQuery = query;
        startListening();
    }.....
```

My CommentsApapter extends this class.

Comment: where are the codes?

Comment: yeah here's the code

Comment: Please only show relevant code and don't just dump the entire Activity here. In the code you've shown you're not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the Adapter before you call `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` on the RecyclerView.